# HTML5 Canvas Physics

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I have the following Canvas application: http://dev.driz.co.uk/canvas/

As you will see it renders a load of balls. The problem I am having is that the balls are being cut-off by the canvas edge when the app first starts. They should not do this they should bounce off the canvas edge if they touch it!

I'm having difficulty sorting the physics out, they bounce off if you move the mouse but not if on the start up.

THANKS

Answer (score 2):

You can just examine, and if any ball is being cut off (it extends past the wall), then just reposition it at the wall, or, move the ball that far from the wall in the direction it should be going.

So, if the ball is 3 pixels past the wall, then you can just position it 3 pixels away from the wall, in the new direction.

This will help in that if your time period is too small, and the balls are moving too fast you can fix it.

**UPDATE:**

After looking at your code, for some reason I can't see it moving in Chrome nor does it draw on Firefox 4b7, but by looking at your code this line may be an issue:

```
Balls[i].x += Balls[i].vx;
```

If `x + vx < 0` then it will still be to the left of the wall.

The reason it can be off is you have this code: `Balls[i].vx *= 0.99;`, which will keep decreasing `vx` before you do your check. You may want to put this at the end, after you made adjustments.

Also, you have both the code for the left and right wall in the same if statement block, which I expect should be handled separately.

To troubleshoot this your best bet is to use Firebug, on Firefox, with one ball, and put a break statement when it goes past a wall, and then see what the values are in each step.

You are also assuming that the balls travel in a straight line, when you adjust, as you are only correcting in one direction, depending on which `if` statement fails, though it can be possible, in case of corners, to have both fail.  That is a failure in your physics model, if I am going at a 45 degree angle and I hit the wall, I should rebound at a 45 degree angle, if the wall is ideal, for example.

Learn to use the debuggers, Chrome, IE and Firefox have good ones, but I tend to prefer to use Firebug, perhaps due to experience with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Fix

```
if (ball[i].x - ball[i].r <= 0 || ball[i].x + ball[i].r >= cwidth) {
    ball[i].vx = -ball[i].vx;
    ball[i].x += ball[i].vx;
}

if (ball[i].y - ball[i].r <= 0 || ball[i].y + ball[i].r >= cheight) {
    ball[i].vy = -ball[i].vy;
    ball[i].y += ball[i].vy;
}
```

Comment: The balls still seem to be getting cut off by the canvas edge though and NOT bouncing off it on start up. I've changed the initial loop so that balls are randomly placed `x  = Math.random() * cwidth  >> 0; y  = Math.random() * cheight >> 0;` but some of them appear offset unless you move them with the mouse. e.g. http://dev.driz.co.uk/pool

Comment: I suggest you learn Basic Math. Seriously dude, I'm not trying to kid you.. okay, just add min && max value, i.e., just establish a range and set the random points in between the range...

Comment: `x = min + Math.random() * ((width - min) - min)`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Are you saying to replace the x and y with this code? `x = min + Math.random() * ((width - min) - min)`

Comment: I won't Give up things easily & that's my not my nature, anyway here's a stupid solution http://jsbin.com/ikaya3/3 , I Guess I don't need to explain the code again.. Do I need to ??

Comment: I'm sorry but not all of us are as strong programmers as others, hence why I am asking n00b questions on a programmer qna website.

Comment: sorry to hurt you dude, I'm just frustrated my daily busy life, I shouldn't have commented in a rude way.. Once again I'm extremely sorry for my rude behavior, I really mean it.

Comment: Hey no need to apologise pal. Your help has been fantastic. I know I'm annoying you :) but did you get chance to look at the other topic concerning the balls stacking when moving the mouse, you mentioned about looking but giving you some time. Once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will *love* the Mozilla Developer Network article: [Basic Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations).

As far as I can tell, you need to update the canvas whenever it changes with the `canvas.restore()` function.

Comment: Hmm I had it working with an older version of my app and didn't use that function: http://dev.driz.co.uk/app/

Comment: Oh well; I've never used the `<canvas>` element much, so I'll give it another go. I'm playing with your demo right now...

Comment: It seems to me that the only difference is that you didn't use the `setInterval()` method in your second demo. The MDN article described two methods of animation: one was using the `.restore()` method, and another with the `setInterval()`. I don't see either, so let me hack a working demo together...

Comment: It seems to be that the balls aren't even getting called by the `for` loop in the `onmousemove` event. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9J5Xv/

Comment: The balls are still being cut off by the edge for me?

Comment: I'm not going to do it *all* for you, as I have better things to do with my time (I'm not trying to be mean, sorry). Lemme go check out the ball problem...

Comment: Okay, I got the balls to not overlap. I'm not sure what the `>> 0` do, so I omitted them (feel free to update the code with the `Update` button). Basically, I changed the `x` and `y` positions to have a min of the ball's radius, and a max of the ball's radius. It's really simple.

Comment: The balls still overlap and get cut off by canvas edge for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Box2D](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) for the physics.

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with your syntax

vX not vx.
vY not vy.

Plus you needed a function to call to render.
Post your final results at jsdo.it ( when you finish the physics ). Looks really cool.

```
window.onload=App 
function App() {
    var pool = document.getElementById('pool');
    var canvas = pool.getContext('2d');
    var cwidth = pool.width = window.innerWidth;
    var cheight = pool.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctop = pool.offsetTop;
    var cleft = pool.offsetLeft;
    var size = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
    var numBalls = 100;
    // CREATES THE BALL
    function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, s) {
        this.color = rgb();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vX = vx;
        this.vY = vy;
        this.r = r;
        this.size = s;
    } 
    // GIVES EACH BALL A RANDOM COLOR
    function rgb() {
        var color = 'rgb(';
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',';
        }
        return color.replace(/\,$/, ')');
    }
     var Balls = [],
        x, y, vx, vy, r, s;
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    x = Math.random() * cwidth >> 0;
    y = Math.random() * cheight >> 0;
    vx = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
    vy = Math.random() * 20 - 6;
    r = Math.random() * 15 + 30;
    s = size[~~(Math.random() * size.length >> 0)];

    // CREATES THE BALLS
    Balls.push(new Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, s));
}
function render(){
// DRAWS THE CANVAS AND BALLS
```

// PHYSICS
  Balls.map(function(item){
        // BALLS SHOULD BOUNCE OFF CANVAS EDGE
        item.vX *= 0.99;
        item.vY *= 0.99;

```
    item.x += item.vX;
    item.y += item.vY;

    if (item.x < item.r ){
        item.vX *= -.99;
        item.x += item.vX;
    }
     if(item.x > pool.width - item.r) {
         item.vX *= -.99;
        item.x += item.vX;
    }
    if (item.y < item.r ){
        item.vY *= -.99;
        item.y += item.vY;
    }
     if( item.y > pool.height - item.r) {
        item.vY *= -1;
        item.y += item.vY;
    }
```

})
   // END PHYSICS
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.canvas.width, canvas.canvas.height);

```
for (var i in Balls) {
    var b = Balls[i];

        var grad = canvas.createRadialGradient(b.x + b.r / 4 ,  b.y - b.r / 4 ,  b.r / 5 , b.x, b.y, b.r);
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
        grad.addColorStop(.85, b.color);
        grad.addColorStop(1, '#222');
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.fillStyle = grad;
        canvas.arc(b.x, b.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0);
        canvas.fill();
 }
```

}

```
// END FOR
// MOUSE MOVEMENT - BALLS SHOULD MOVE AWAY FROM MOUSE CURSOR
pool.onmousemove = function(e) {
    x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    for (i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(x - Balls[i].x) < 20 && Math.abs(y - Balls[i].y) < 20 ) {
            Balls[i].vX = (x - Balls[i].x)  ;
            Balls[i].vY = (y - Balls[i].y)  ;

        }
    }
};
```

setInterval(render,50);

`// END APP`

};